# Gerund question: Is it wrong to use the infinitive in a sentence like "I like to work from home."

Tags: grammar, gerunds

I know that we use gerunds for many likes and dislikes, but are there exceptions? I feel that I have heard the above expression many times in my life, but that could be because many people were using it incorrectly.

Comment: It's not an exception, just a different way of saying it. You can like _doing_ something, or you can like _to do_ it.

Comment: The verb "like" can take both _to_-infinitival clauses and gerund-participial ones as complement.